# jQuery Serialization Array Syntax

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-3

The POST string that is created from serializing one of my JavaScript objects looks like this when posted to my webpage:

`bikeID=1&vehicleID=23&VIN=1HD1FB416AB666666&slotNum=0&alias=Betsy&BikeCustomizations[0][ CustomizationTypeID] =1&BikeCustomizations[0][ ManufacturerID] =4&BikeCustomizations[0][ CustomizationSubTypeID] =1&BikeCustomizations[1][ CustomizationTypeID] =2&BikeCustomizations[1][ ManufacturerID] =-1`

This is posted to my ASP.NET MVC 3 application.  I get the base attributes "bikeID, and I get the correct number of items in `BikeCustomizations` (2 in this case), but those objects do not have values.

If I change the POST string and re-post (using Fiddler) to the below, the de-serialization works fine:

`bikeID=1&vehicleID=23&VIN=1HD1FB416AB666666&slotNum=0&alias=Betsy&BikeCustomizations[0].CustomizationTypeID=1&BikeCustomizations[0].ManufacturerID=4&BikeCustomizations[0].CustomizationSubTypeID=1&BikeCustomizations[1].CustomizationTypeID=2&BikeCustomizations[1].ManufacturerID=-1`

You can see that the difference is `BikeCustomizations[1][ CustomizationTypeID] =2` vs `BikeCustomizations[1].CustomizationTypeID=2`.

The question: is there any way to force the stringification of the object to not use the funky array style property setter syntax?

Here is the JavaScript of the object creation:

```
Cust.buildBike = function (bikeObj) {
if (bikeObj != undefined)
    this.bike = bikeObj;
else
    this.bike = { bikeID: -1 };

this.bike.BikeCustomizations = new Array();
var that = this;

$.each(this.customizationsArr, function (key, obj) {
    if (obj == undefined)
        return true;

    var typeID = obj.ID,
        SubTypeID = obj.SubTypeID,
        ManufacturerID = obj.ManufacturerID,
        Model = obj.Model;

    if (ManufacturerID == -1)
        SubTypeID = undefined;

    that.bike.BikeCustomizations.push({
        CustomizationTypeID: typeID,
        ManufacturerID: ManufacturerID,
        CustomizationSubTypeID: SubTypeID,
        Model: Model
    });
});

return this.bike;
}

...

$('#customizationPageNext').click(function () {
var data = Cust.buildBike(bikeObj);

$.mobile.changePage('/Selection/Calibrations/', { data: data });
});
```

Comment: what does the html look like that you are serializing?

Comment: maybe you want [.serializeArray()](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/)

Comment: maybe i'm not understanding but that isn't JSON. those just look like on object serialized as params